# how to log command start time and command end time in txt file using cygwin

Tags: bash, logs, timestamps, date-utility

I can save and view the cygwin console output (stdout and stderr) using the following command,

```
python command.py 2>&1 | tee -a outFile.txt// Note -a is for appending
```

since I have different commands and they take different time to execute. How can I save the start time like

```
09:00:00AM
file stream file stream file stream file stream 
file stream file stream file stream file stream 
.
.
.
file stream file stream file stream file stream 
09:07:20AM
```

Note the start and end time stamp. It would be awesome if I could log the diff time

```
Total execution time: 00:07:20
```

Yes I can get the time using date command in cygwin,

```
$ date -> Tue, Mar 22, 2016  12:00:47 AM
```

but do I have to parse this date to get the time in variable and then take diff to get time elapsed?

Comment: Maybe there is another option. You could use the command `time` to print timing statistics, eg. `time python command.py 2>&1 | tee -a outFile.txt`. Use `man time` for more info. I'm not sure if this is available on `cygwin`.

Comment: Try to execute this `time ls`. What is the output? For me, it's something like this:

`file1 file 2 file3`

`real   0m0.003s`
`user  0m0.003s`
`sys    0m0.000s`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8903239/how-to-calculate-time-difference-in-bash-script

Comment: close, but none of the suggested answers combine a readable form of the date with the elapsed time.

Answer (score 1):

The following **SEQUENCE of commands** I have tried to achieve the start/end and elapsed time in the log file. There might be a better way of doing this.

```
date 2>&1 | tee -a outFile.txt && SECONDS=0 && command.py 2>&1 | tee -a outFile.txt && date 2>&1 | tee -a outFile.txt && duration=$SECONDS echo "Total Execution Time: $(($duration / 60)) m $(($duration % 60)) s" 2>&1 | tee -a outFile.txt
```

1. Its just getting start date and appending to file,

   ```
   date 2>&1 | tee -a outFile.txt
   ```
2. then executing command and appending to file,

   ```
   && SECONDS=0 && command.py 2>&1 | tee -a outFile.txt
   ```
3. then getting end date and appending to file.

   ```
   && date 2>&1 | tee -a outFile.txt
   ```
4. and at last calculating elapsed time and appending to file

   ```
   && duration=$SECONDS echo "Total Execution Time: $(($duration / 60)) m $(($duration % 60)) s" 2>&1 | tee -a outFile.txt
   ```

The following is the output of the log file,

```
    Tue, Mar 22, 2016  4:01:18 PM

    file stream file stream file stream file stream 
    file stream file stream file stream file stream 
    .
    .
    .
    file stream file stream file stream file stream 
    Tue, Mar 22, 2016  4:01:23 PM
    Total Execution Time: 0 m 7 s
```